# Как сделать так, чтоб vcpkg скачивал библиотеки в usr/local, а не в свою директорию pakage?

Tags: c++, linux, библиотеки, vcpkg

Как сделать так, чтоб vcpkg скачивал библиотеки в usr/local, а не в свою директорию pakage?(на ubuntu)

Comment: Не стоит захламлять usr/local сторонними файлами

Comment: @user7860670 /usr/local — это место, _предназначенное_ для сторонних файлов.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Ничего подобного